# What is the generator method for probability prediction in Keras?

Tags: keras, generator, probability, prediction

I want to predict probabilities for a bi-classification problem. Previously I was using model.predict_proba or predict_on_batch for this issue. Now I want to use generators in my scripts, but I can't find a generator such as evaluate_generator or predict_generator. Both of evaluate_generator or predict_generator won't generate probabilities. What is the generator method for probability prediction in Keras?

Comment: Which Keras version do you use? it seems Keras has `evaluate_generator` and `predict_generator`, and the `predict_generator` returns a Numpy array of predictions(probability). See [Keras Sequential](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the output  is a probability or not depends on the actual neural network model, not on `predict_generator`. If your model already outputs probabilities, meaning it has a softmax activation at the output, then using `predict_generator` should give you probability values.